# how to connect GoDaddy host to a domain?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, godaddy

Having a domain and a host server, the server is GoDaddy but the domain isn't. how to connect those two together?

Comment: You just need to point your domain to Godaddy name server. If you have any problems, then you can contact them

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy should have provided you with nameservers for your hosting. Simply go to your domain registrar and change the nameservers to Godaddy's.

Answer (score 0):

*This question belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, not Web Applications.  However, it's not a very good question in that it doesn't reflect what research, if any, you've done, and it doesn't even give someone else enough information to do the research (e.g. who's the registrar?).   Please check out https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.*

---

To the extent an answer is possible, it is that you have to change settings at your domain registrar to point to the IP address of your server at GoDaddy.  The domain registry's primary functionality is to act as a lookup table mapping domain names to IP addresses, and when you buy the domain name the main thing you purchase is the right to control what IP address that domain name redirects to.  Your registrar should provide instructions for how to exercise that right, and GoDaddy should provide instructions about what IP address to redirect to.